uncaught exception: error(instantiation_error,(=<)/2)
Im trying to code a board thats 7x7 and I need to set and check the limits of the board, so I made de following function:
lim(X, Y) :- 
    X =< 7,
    X >= 1,
    Y =< 7,
    Y >= 1.

But it keeps giving me the error "uncaught exception: error(instantiation_error,(=<)/2)".
Does anyone have any idea of how to fix this?
I tried to change to:
lim(X, Y) :- 
    X < 8,
    X > 0,
    Y < 8,
    Y > 0.

But it gives me the error "uncaught exception: error(instantiation_error,(<)/2)", and I dont know what to do.
I tried to search the error as well and what I saw said that this error ocurs because I do not use the variables X and Y, so I changed it to X -> La and Y -> Ca, this are the variables that I use but the same error appears, so this is the new limit function:
lim(La, Ca) :- 
    La =< 7,
    La >= 1,
    Ca =< 7,
    Ca >= 1.

For more context the first part of the code is as follows:
% state -> e(AgentLine, AgentColumn, MachineLine, MachineColumn)

inicial_state(e(1, 2, 2, 2)).
final_state(e(_, _, 7, 2)).

%restrictions
obsta(e(6, 1)).
obsta(e(6, 3)).
obsta(e(7, 4)).
obsta(e(4, 4)).
obsta(e(3, 4)).
obsta(e(2, 4)).
obsta(e(6, 7)).

lim(La, Ca) :- 
    La =< 7,
    La >= 1,
    Ca =< 7,
    Ca >= 1.

equals(A, A).

%state operator -> op(actual_state, operator, next_state, cost)
op(e(La, Ca, Lm, Cm), up, e(Ls, Cs, Lms, Cms), 1) :-
    Ls is La + 1.


Lim is not a function but a predicate that need to run on instantiated La and Ça.

Just use: between(1, 7, X), between(1, 7, Y).

The "between" worked, thank u!

Cheers @Pietro thanks for the confirmation.

Just use: between(1, 7, X), between(1, 7, Y).
Credits to: brebs
